# How to reinstall all user packages after updating Python version in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, package

I have a Windows 7 machine running Python 3.8.5 with a very large number of physics/electronics/data analysis/simulation packages. As it turned out, I must have - for some inexplicable reason - installed the 32-bit version of Python instead of the 64-bit one despite having a 64-bit system. And I didn't notice until very recently when I was trying to install some packages that require 64-bit Python. Hence I've now downloaded and installed the latest Python version that is supported by Windows 7, which seems to be 3.8.10.

Question: What is the easiest and also fail-safe way to reinstall all the user packages - that I currently have under 3.8.5 - to 3.8.10?

For some reason, I couldn't find any "canonical" solution for this online. As it seems, Python does not come with any built-in support for updating or system migration and I'm honestly wondering why...

Anyway, my first idea was to get a list of all user (= "local"?) packages currently installed under 3.8.5, but I don't know how. Reason: Doing `help('modules')` inside the interpreter will list **all** packages and I don't see a way to "selectively apply" `pip` to a specific Python version, e.g. something like `python-3.8.5 -m pip list --local` is not supported.

After getting a list of the user packages, I was thinking to pack it into a batch command `pip install package_1 package_2 <...> package_N`, thus reinstalling everything to Python 3.8.10. And afterwards uninstalling Python 3.8.5 and removing all environment variables from system PATH.

Is this the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> Anyway, my first idea was to get a list of all user (= "local"?) packages currently installed under 3.8.5, but I don't know how.

Create a list of installed packages with `pip freeze > pkglist.txt` or `pip list --format=freeze`. If you already have one, that's great.

Then uninstall 32-bit Python 3.8.5 and clean your path for all Python related variables. Now, install 64-bit Python 3.8.10.

After reinstalling, you can install back all the packages with `pip install -r pkglist.txt` and it will restore the exact versions of the packages.

If you insist on having both 32-bit and 64-bit versions installed and also have the Python Launcher installed, you could invoke 32 and 64 bit versions separately with `py -3.8-64 -m pip` and `py -3.8-32 -m pip`.

> I don't see a way to "selectively apply" pip to a specific Python version.

This is possible with the Python Launcher on Windows. But only between major/minor versions and not the patch versions according to its help message.

I would also recommend creating a virtual environment this time before installing the packages and leaving the root environment alone. You can create one named `venv` with just `python -m venv venv`, activate it with `./venv/Scripts/activate` and proceed with the installation of packages.

> Nope, doesn't work. After installing the packages with the newer Python version in PATH, e.g. Jupyter won't start.

If the Jupyter error persists, you could try pinning packages to their most recent patch/minor versions to update them and yet not break your code.

As a last resort, you could try installing Python 3.10 alongside your current Python installation (without uninstall or editing the PATH) and then installing the absolute latest versions of the packages in a 3.10 virtual environment to see if it works for you. You would invoke the two versions with Py Launcher, e.g. `py -3.10` and `py -3.8`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have multiple packages like NumPy, pandas etc. installed on your machine, and you want to reinstall them "automatically" on a fresh installation of python.

The method (I use) to perform such an operation is by creating a file named `setup.py` which includes a list of all the packages.
Bellow, I am attaching an example of such a file I use in one of my projects:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='surface_quality_tools',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=["matplotlib", "psutil", "numpy", "scipy", "pandas", "trimesh", "pyglet", "networkx", "protobuf",
                      "numpy-stl", "sklearn", "opencv-python", "seaborn", "scikit-image", "flask", "tqdm", "pytest"],
    package_data={'': ['*.json']},
    packages=find_packages(include=[])
)
```

to run the installation you should open a command prompt from inside the project directory and run:

`pip install -e .`

You can find a nice example in this blog [page](https://godatadriven.com/blog/a-practical-guide-to-using-setup-py)

Answer (score -1):

One common way of handling packages in Python is via virtual environments. You can use Anaconda (conda), venv or any of several other solutions. For example, see this post:

[https://towardsdatascience.com/virtual-environments-104c62d48c54#:~:text=A%20virtual%20environment%20is%20a,a%20system%2Dwide%20Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/virtual-environments-104c62d48c54#:%7E:text=A%20virtual%20environment%20is%20a,a%20system%2Dwide%20Python)).

The way this works in by keeping the Python interpreter separate from the virtual environment that contains all the necessary packages.

Probably the main reason Python doesn't feature migration tools (at least as part of standard library) is because `pip` - the main package tool - doesn't handle conflict resolution all too well. When you update a version of Python it might so happen (especially with niche packages) that some of them won't work any more and pip often won't be able to solve the dependencies. This is why it's a good idea to keep a separate venv for different Python versions and different projects.

The other tool you could use for easy migration is [Docker](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/a-beginners-guide-to-understanding-and-building-docker-images/) which is a semi-virtual machine working on top of your host OS and containing usually some linux distribution, Python along with the necessary packages necessary for running and development.

It takes a bit of time to set up a container image initially but afterwards setting everythin on a new machine or in the cloud becomes a breeze.

Listing currently installed packages is done via `pip freeze` command, the output of which you can then pipe into a file to keep a record of project requirements, for example `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Comment: The goal is not to containerize - it simply does not solve my problem. Yes, I've read about Docker, but I'm not dealing with cross-platform deployment issues. *I'm currently on Windows 7* and I'm not goint to set up an entirely new system as there is a ton of equipment connected to this machine used for ongoing experiments. Furthermore, `pip freeze` (which is supposed to be equivalent to `pip list`) does not list all my packages. As explained in the question, I need a list of user packages that are **installed under a specific Python version**. Is `pip` able to do this?

Comment: @kerstin92, if you haven't set up a virtual environment, all packages will be installed under the python version that's listed in your Path. So to list all packages installed under 3.8.5 you need to put your Python 3.8.5 interpreter into Path (and ensure 3.8.10 is not in Path) and then run `pip freeze` or you can also specify `--path` argument for pip freeze to list packages installed under a specific location https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/   You can also add `--all` flag to pip freeze to list all packages.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. After installing the packages with the newer Python version in PATH, e.g. Jupyter won't start: `ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\guest\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)`

Comment: What a **MESS**!!! Doing `python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip` results in `WARNING: No metadata found in c:\users\guest\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages [...] Rolling back uninstall of pip [...] ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib`

Comment: This all is easily avoided if you use virtual environments. This is exactly the reason why no one works with global environments. I would strongly suggest to stop torturing the system and install all necessary packages into a virtual environment.